# Django Auth Query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a django backend project for e-commerce site where I have created authentication class which is used by all the view classes for incoming requests. In one of the classes I have get_queryset, put and post functions overridden. I want the authentication class to be applied for both put and post functions but not to get_queryset. following are the code snippets,

**Authentication Class**

```
class JWTAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        print('authenticating')
        auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()
        print(auth)
        if auth and len(auth) == 2:
            token = auth[1].decode('utf-8')
            print('Decoded Token')
            print(token)
            id = decode_access_token(token)
            print(id)
            print(id)
            customer = models.Customer.objects.get(id=id)
            return (customer, None)
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('unauthenticated2')
```

**Product View class**

```
class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ...
    authentication_classes = [ JWTAuthentication ]
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...

    def post(self, request):
        ...

    def put...
```

Is there a way just to apply the authentication on put and post function but not on get_queryset function?

Comment: The post, put, patch and get methods are the ones that are called when appropriate HTTP request is being made. At this stage one of the base classes calls the authentication machinery to do the actual authentication. Based on the results either an exception will be raised or the underlying code will be called.

Some of that code might call the get_queryset method. 

The bottom line here is that one cannot directly configure the get_queryset to be private or exposed as this is not the intended target for the authentication machinery. 

If you meant the get method - that's another story.

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a way to have different authentication mechanism for post method and put method?

Comment: Technically yes. However I would consider splitting these into separate Views. Most probably having different authentication flows means the methods would be used in a different manner, from a different client app or role. If this is the case, create 2 views, name them appropriately. Each will be tailored for a specific use case (role, app, etc.) This will ease the maintenance which most certainly will occur later on during the app lifecycle. No need to use a single view for the sake of using single view though technically possible. Simply a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, will consider dividing the views. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by simply overriding the authentication method like below:

```
def get_authentication_classes(self):
    if self.request.method in ['POST', 'PUT']:
        return [JWTAuthentication]
    return [AllowAny]
```

Comment: This method doesn't get called before any request. I added this function and a couple of print statements but didn't see the logs.